# .htaccess error 500 on RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This line cause an 500 error in apache :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/artist/artist.php?seo=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Here is my all htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.test.fr/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/artist/artist.php?seo=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas why ?

Comment: Look into the server’s error log.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're creating an infinite loop error.

Your rule will always match and will execute on and on.
Example:

```
http://www.test.fr/this/url/is/cool
```

will be rewritten to

```
/frontend/artist/artist.php?seo=this/url/is/cool
```

which will also be rewritten because your rule matches everything without exception.

And so on...

**Solution**

To avoid this behaviour, you can add a simple condition (check if it's an existing file or not)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/artist/artist.php?seo=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```